# Bluetooth controller connects/disconnects spamming system logs

Tags: usb, bluetooth, udev, 15.04

I'm running one of the new Broadwell NUCs under 15.04. Bluetooth has been "fine" for the last few weeks (didn't use it beyong testing it with a BT mouse). Yesterday I started seeing continuous spam explode in syslog and dmesg. So far the only workaround I've found is to blacklist `btusb` in `/etc/modules/blacklist.conf` and then reboot.

The messages started when the machine was unattended, and the last updates to udev and the kernel were days before. I tried cold reboots, then using older kernels, unplugging everything else USB, turning on/off secure boot -- nothing. The line `hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-19)` from the kernel seems key but I have no idea what -19 means or where to look it up. Where can I find more info, or am I missing something relevant in the logs?

dmesg spam immediately after `sudo modprobe btusb`:

```
[  +0.000001] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  +0.000004] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  +0.000002] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  +0.000004] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  +0.003016] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[  +0.024109] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  +0.000003] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  +0.000004] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  +1.713419] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 13
[  +0.000275] Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-19)
[  +0.272765] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.128553] usb 1-7: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
[  +0.000875] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2a
[  +0.000004] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  +1.745806] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 15
[  +0.000190] Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-19)
[  +0.273130] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.128570] usb 1-7: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
[  +0.000934] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2a
[  +0.000004] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  +1.738841] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 16
```

syslog spam after setting `udev_log="debug"` in `/etc/udev/udev.conf`:

```
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc kernel: [ 1029.613724] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 100 using xhci_hcd
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: seq 4855 queued, 'add' 'usb'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: passed 276 bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f33770d0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4855 running
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: no db file to read /run/udev/data/c189:99: No such file or directory
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is '���������������������������������'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2-6.rules:11
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: seq 4856 queued, 'add' 'usb'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: seq 4857 queued, 'add' 'bluetooth'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: seq 4858 queued, 'add' 'rfkill'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: seq 4859 queued, 'add' 'usb'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: IMPORT builtin skip 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:9
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:9
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc kernel: [ 1029.742320] usb 1-7: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc kernel: [ 1029.743246] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc kernel: [ 1029.743251] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: MODE 0664 /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:41
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: handling device node '/dev/bus/usb/001/100', devnum=c189:99, mode=0664, uid=0, gid=0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: set permissions /dev/bus/usb/001/100, 020664, uid=0, gid=0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: creating symlink '/dev/char/189:99' to '../bus/usb/001/100'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: created db file '/run/udev/data/c189:99' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: passed unknown number of bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f338db10
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4855 processed with 0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: passed 294 bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f33770d0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: passed 307 bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f33770d0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: seq 4859 running
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4856 running
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: no db file to read /run/udev/data/+usb:1-7:1.1: No such file or directory
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: no db file to read /run/udev/data/+usb:1-7:1.0: No such file or directory
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is '���������������������������������'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:11
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: RUN 'kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: created db file '/run/udev/data/+usb:1-7:1.1' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: Execute 'load' 'usb:v8087p0A2Ad0001dcE0dsc01dp01icE0isc01ip01in01'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is '���������������������������������'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: Inserted 'btusb'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: passed unknown number of bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f3383470
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: seq 4859 processed with 0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:11
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: RUN 'kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: created db file '/run/udev/data/+usb:1-7:1.0' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: Execute 'load' 'usb:v8087p0A2Ad0001dcE0dsc01dp01icE0isc01ip01in00'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: Inserted 'btusb'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: passed unknown number of bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f338db10
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4856 processed with 0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: passed 197 bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f33770d0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4857 running
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: no db file to read /run/udev/data/+bluetooth:hci0: No such file or directory
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is '���������������������������������'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: created db file '/run/udev/data/+bluetooth:hci0' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: passed unknown number of bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f338db10
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: passed 245 bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f33770d0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4857 processed with 0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4858 running
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: no db file to read /run/udev/data/+rfkill:rfkill204: No such file or directory
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is '���������������������������������'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1544]: sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device changed dead -> plugged
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device changed dead -> plugged
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules:13
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1544]: sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device changed dead -> plugged
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device changed dead -> plugged
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: created db file '/run/udev/data/+rfkill:rfkill204' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill204'
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Trying to enqueue job bluetooth.target/start/fail
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: passed unknown number of bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f338db10
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Installed new job bluetooth.target/start as 24475
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4858 processed with 0
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Enqueued job bluetooth.target/start as 24475
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1544]: sys-subsystem-rfkill-devices-rfkill204.device changed dead -> plugged
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitNew cookie=6735 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1544]: sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0-rfkill204.device changed dead -> plugged
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitNew cookie=6736 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitNew cookie=6737 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=JobNew cookie=6738 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-rfkill-devices-rfkill204.device changed dead -> plugged
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0-rfkill204.device changed dead -> plugged
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Trying to enqueue job systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service/start/fail
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Installed new job systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service/start as 24574
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Enqueued job systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service/start as 24574
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitNew cookie=6739 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitNew cookie=6740 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitNew cookie=6741 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=JobNew cookie=6742 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: About to execute: /lib/systemd/systemd-rfkill load rfkill204
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Forked /lib/systemd/systemd-rfkill as 5600
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service changed dead -> start
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill204...
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: bluetooth.target changed dead -> active
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Job bluetooth.target/start finished, result=done
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=JobRemoved cookie=6743 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth.
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/bluetooth_2etarget interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6744 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/systemd_2drfkill_40rfkill204_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6745 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/systemd_2drfkill_40rfkill204_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6746 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/job/24574 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6747 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[5600]: Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-rfkill load rfkill204
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd-rfkill[5600]: Operating on rfkill device 'hci0'.
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 5600 (systemd-rfkill).
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Child 5600 (systemd-rfkill) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Child 5600 belongs to systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service changed start -> exited
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Job systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service/start finished, result=done
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill204.
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=JobRemoved cookie=6748 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service: cgroup is empty
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/systemd_2drfkill_40rfkill204_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6749 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/systemd_2drfkill_40rfkill204_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6750 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Got message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc colord[1063]: (colord:1063): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'g_utf8_validate (string, -1, NULL)' failed
Apr 18 11:22:05 nuc colord[1063]: unable to receive message
Apr 18 11:22:06 nuc systemd[1]: Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=NameOwnerChanged cookie=768 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc kernel: [ 1031.482014] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 100
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc kernel: [ 1031.482224] Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-19)
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: Validate module index
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: Check if link configuration needs reloading.
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: seq 4860 queued, 'remove' 'rfkill'
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: passed 248 bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f33770d0
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: seq 4861 queued, 'remove' 'bluetooth'
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: seq 4862 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: seq 4863 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: passed 297 bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f33770d0
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: seq 4863 running
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: seq 4864 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is '���������������������������������'
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:11
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: passed unknown number of bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f3383470
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2371]: seq 4863 processed with 0
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4860 running
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is '���������������������������������'
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1544]: sys-subsystem-rfkill-devices-rfkill204.device changed plugged -> dead
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1544]: sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0-rfkill204.device changed plugged -> dead
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: passed unknown number of bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f338db10
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4860 processed with 0
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-rfkill-devices-rfkill204.device changed plugged -> dead
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: passed 200 bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f33770d0
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4861 running
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Trying to enqueue job systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service/stop/replace
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1544]: Collecting sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0-rfkill204.device
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is '���������������������������������'
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Installed new job systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service/stop as 24586
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1544]: Collecting sys-subsystem-rfkill-devices-rfkill204.device
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Enqueued job systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service/stop as 24586
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0-rfkill204.device changed plugged -> dead
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1544]: sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device changed plugged -> dead
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: passed unknown number of bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f338db10
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Collecting sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0-rfkill204.device
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1544]: sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device changed plugged -> dead
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: passed 297 bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f33770d0
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4861 processed with 0
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitRemoved cookie=6751 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1544]: Collecting sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4862 running
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/sys_2dsubsystem_2drfkill_2ddevices_2drfkill204_2edevice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6752 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1544]: Collecting sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is '���������������������������������'
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/sys_2dsubsystem_2drfkill_2ddevices_2drfkill204_2edevice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6753 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:11
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=JobNew cookie=6754 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: passed unknown number of bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f338db10
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device changed plugged -> dead
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4862 processed with 0
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: passed 279 bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f33770d0
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device changed plugged -> dead
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4864 running
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Unit bluetooth.target is not needed anymore. Stopping.
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is '���������������������������������'
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Trying to enqueue job bluetooth.target/stop/fail
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:9
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Installed new job bluetooth.target/stop as 24587
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: No USB vendor information available
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Enqueued job bluetooth.target/stop as 24587
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' returned non-zero
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Collecting sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: passed unknown number of bytes to netlink monitor 0x7fd5f338db10
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Collecting sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitRemoved cookie=6755 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[2370]: seq 4864 processed with 0
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitRemoved cookie=6756 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=JobNew cookie=6757 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: bluetooth.target changed active -> dead
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Job bluetooth.target/stop finished, result=done
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=JobRemoved cookie=6758 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth.
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: About to execute: /lib/systemd/systemd-rfkill save rfkill204
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Forked /lib/systemd/systemd-rfkill as 5602
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service changed exited -> stop
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Stopping Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill204...
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Collecting bluetooth.target
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitRemoved cookie=6759 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/systemd_2drfkill_40rfkill204_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6760 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/systemd_2drfkill_40rfkill204_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6761 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/job/24586 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6762 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[5602]: Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-rfkill save rfkill204
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-rfkill[5602]: Failed to get rfkill device 'rfkill204', ignoring: No such file or directory
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 5602 (systemd-rfkill).
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Child 5602 (systemd-rfkill) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Child 5602 belongs to systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service: control process exited, code=exited status=0
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service got final SIGCHLD for state stop
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service changed stop -> dead
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Job systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service/stop finished, result=done
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Stopped Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill204.
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=JobRemoved cookie=6763 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service: cgroup is empty
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Collecting systemd-rfkill@rfkill204.service
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitRemoved cookie=6764 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Collecting sys-subsystem-rfkill-devices-rfkill204.device
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitRemoved cookie=6765 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd-udevd[259]: error opening USB device 'descriptors' file
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Got message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Got message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Apr 18 11:22:07 nuc systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
```

usb:1-7 is indeed the Intel bluetooth device:

```
$ udevadm info --query=all /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-7:1.0
calling: info
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0
E: DEVTYPE=usb_interface
E: DRIVER=btusb
E: ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Wireless
E: ID_USB_PROTOCOL_FROM_DATABASE=Bluetooth
E: ID_USB_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Radio Frequency
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Intel Corp.
E: INTERFACE=224/1/1
E: MODALIAS=usb:v8087p0A2Ad0001dcE0dsc01dp01icE0isc01ip01in00
E: PRODUCT=8087/a2a/1
```

Comment: I have the same problem, it causes me not being able to use bluetooth devices. Did you find a solution to it?

Comment: Same problem here, running 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient thread, but I will resurrect it for the sake of those sharing this frustration, which continues to this day...

See this thread on the Intel site:
https://communities.intel.com/message/311296?tstart=0#311296

Apparently shutting down and unplugging the NUC for a few minutes fixes the problem. (forever?) I hope this helps.

Rich

Comment: Worked for me, by the way...